# Getting driverClassName with external tomcat using JNDI into spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi, tomcat9

I have a spring boot application with datasource  configured on external tomcat,
How  can I get the driverClassName of the datasource configured by the external tomcat into my spring boot application.

I tried to write some code as

```
PoolProperties poolProps = new PoolProperties();
Properties dbProperties = poolProps.getDbProperties();
String databaseUrl = dbProperties.getProperty("databaseUrl");
```

But the **databaseUrl** in the above code returns null. Can anyone suggest How can I get driverClassName into my java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the JavaBean properties of your datasource through reflection. Just use one of the many tools that help with introspection.

Since you already have `spring-beans` as dependency you can use:

```java
final BeanWrapper accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(dataSource);
final String url = String.valueOf(accessor.getPropertyValue("url"));
```

You can also use reflection directly, but it becomes easily difficult to read:

```java
try {
    final String value = String.valueOf(dataSource.getClass().getMethod("getUrl").invoke(dataSource));
} catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the JNDI name?

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=<the name configured in tomcat>
```

Comment: Yes, I did use it to configure JNDI in spring boot application, but How can I get the datasource properties like driverClassName or so, programmatically.

Comment: You can't. That's not possible

Comment: So how can I get the datasource properties

Comment: As I said you can't. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to create a healthcheck REST endpoint which displays datasource information

Comment: Then my question is why do you use a data source configured in Tomcat? You can't do both

Comment: Then how to check whether database is up?

Comment: That will spring boot Actuator do for you. Just add the starter. You dint have to code anything

Comment: Using spring boot actuator, how can I get access to the datasource properties in my REST endpoint (I know that actuator provides health check, but I want to get this information in the REST controller).